# Delete bad practice Questions?

Tags: discussion

I found [this Question asking »How to change the wp-admin folder name«](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43560/how-do-i-rename-the-wp-admin-folder-with-the-admin-url-filter-fixed#comment55208_43560) and had a long time in the comments. The outcoming was, as [Dion Hulse stated on wp-hackers](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=de#!topic/wp-hackers/yyApdV_8Npk), that it's simply not supported, has a lot of caveats, etc.

Now the OP thinks that his Q is solved (added `FIXED` to the title, which I removed). How should we handle this Q? Delete it - I already flagged it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is good practice and what is not depends very much on personal opinions. Add your objections in a comment and let it stay as is. Now your objections have a permanent address, and you don’t have to repeat them each time the topic comes up.
Different perspectives should have a place on WPSE.

Comment: +1. Again, this is an opportunity to use the built-in site mechanisms, including downvoting questions, and leaving comments. If we delete a question, it will very likely reappear in the future, and just have to be dealt with again. If we leave the original question, we can cross-reference/close any similar, future questions.

Answer (score 1):

Questions about how to do things that are bad practice shouldn't be deleted because:

- Someone will ask the question again
- Its an opportunity to point out bad practice
- Its an opportunity to show viable alternatives
- It educates users who aren't aware
- It helps prevent people falling into traps and pitfalls
- If you disagree that it's bad practice you have a chance to argue your case and change the tide
- Sometimes the user is aware it is bad practice but has been forced down that route for other reasons. I'm not the first to have to do things like modify WordPress core for a client while a patch is waiting for acceptance in core trac